# Qt application doesn't display images

Tags: linux, qt, gnu

I have developed an application (using Qt Creator) that employs some pictures for background and icons. Now I am trying to deploy it, the application is successfully installed with:

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The installation directory is `/usr/local/ctimer/`, the binary is located in `/usr/local/ctimer/ctimer`. The problem is that when I execute the program, for example, with the Alt + F2 `/usr/local/ctimer/ctimer` the images aren't displayed.

I have noticed that if I execute the program from its folder all works fine:

```
$ cd /usr/local/ctimer/
$ ./ctimer
```

It's possible to work around the problem with a bash script with the above commands in it and put it in `/usr/local/bin/` for example but I want to know why this behavior.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code:

```
void Stopwatch::createMenu()
{
  startAction = new QAction(QIcon("pictures/start.png"), tr("&Start/Continue"), this);
  startAction->setToolTip("Start/Continue stopwatch");
  startAction->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_S);
  connect(startAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(start()));

  pauseAction = new QAction(QIcon("pictures/pause.png"), tr("&Pause"), this);
  pauseAction->setToolTip("Pause stopwatch");
  pauseAction->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_P);
  connect(pauseAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(pause()));

  resetAction = new QAction(QIcon("pictures/reset.png"), tr("&Reset"), this);
  resetAction->setToolTip("Reset stopwatch");
  resetAction->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_C);
  connect(resetAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(reset()));

  countDownAction = new QAction(QIcon("pictures/down.png"), tr("&Countdown"), this);
  countDownAction->setToolTip("Create a custom count down");
  countDownAction->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_D);
  connect(countDownAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),
          countDownDialog, SLOT(show()));

  aboutAction = new QAction(QIcon("pictures/about.png"), tr("&About"), this);
  aboutAction->setToolTip("About this timer!");
  aboutAction->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_H);
  connect(aboutAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), aboutDialog, SLOT(show()));


  quitAction = new QAction(QIcon("pictures/quit.png"), tr("&Quit"), this);
  quitAction->setToolTip("Quit timer!");
  quitAction->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_Q);
  connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));

  contextMenu = new QMenu(this);

  contextMenu->addAction(startAction);
  contextMenu->addAction(pauseAction);
  contextMenu->addAction(resetAction);
  contextMenu->addAction(countDownAction);
  contextMenu->addAction(aboutAction);
  contextMenu->addAction(quitAction);

  this->addAction(startAction);
  this->addAction(pauseAction);
  this->addAction(resetAction);
  this->addAction(countDownAction);
  this->addAction(aboutAction);
  this->addAction(quitAction);
}
```

Comment: So can we assume the images are loaded from disk?  If so, show us the code where you perform the loading.  I should also state that if the images are not to be changed, it's customary to compile them into the executable using a `.qrc` file (unless they're massive of course).

Comment: Try adding a `./` in front of `pictures`.

Comment: I have solved the problem using the `.qrc` file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For icons I would just use a resource file, as you did.

If you want to store other files inside executable's directory (or children directories) you can prepend the string returned from [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath):

```
QString prefix = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
QIcon startIcon(prefix + "/pictures/start.png");
startAction = new QAction(startIcon, tr("&Start/Continue"), this);
...
```

However this does not comply with Linux / Unix filesystem, since the executable will likely be in `/usr/bin` and you can not really put resources in that directory. You might store resources in some other location (e.g. `/usr/share/yourapp`) and store that directory in some location in `/etc` during installation. Then your application gets the resources directory via [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html).

See [this note](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#locations-where-application-settings-are-stored) to decide what is the best location for storing that information (you can however read any file with QSettings).

```
QSettings settings(QSettings::SystemScope,
                   QCoreApplication::organizationName(),
                   QCoreApplication::applicationName());
// This points to /etc/xdg/MySoft.conf on Unix.

QString prefix = settings.value("resourcesDirectory");
// Inside /etc/xdg/MySoft.conf you have a 'resourcesDirectory'
// entry with value '/usr/share/MySoft/resources'

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually I don't answer my own questions but it's necessary due to lack of response.

The problem regarding to images has been solved using a resource file but the same problem occurs with other files such as sounds, and the same recipe doesn't work for that.

When the application is executed the program adopts my current directory as its base directory, Then the problem.

The solution is create a Bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
$ cd /path/to/myprogram/
$ ./myprogram
```

and put it in `/usr/local/bin/` or `/usr/bin/`.

Maybe this isn't the best solution, but it works. If anyone have a better solution please share it.